# Android Image not loading in Imageview

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I am using a library (https://github.com/darsh2/MultipleImageSelect) for selecting images from phone and then to display it in the Imageview.Some images load efficiently,but some of them do not load at all. I have googled to find solution but didn't find any.Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Below is the code:

```
 photo_choose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddPharmacy.this, AlbumSelectActivity.class);
                //set limit on number of images that can be selected, default is 10
                intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_LIMIT, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == Constants.REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            //The array list has the image paths of the selected images
            ArrayList<Image> images = data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(Constants.INTENT_EXTRA_IMAGES);
            for(int i=0;i<images.size();i++){
                String path=images.get(i).path;
                if(i==0){

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(path).skipMemoryCache(true).into(img1);
                    path1 = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("."));
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you get valid `path`?

Comment: Let me log the path.But some images do load

Comment: /storage/extSdCard/Report-the-Problem.png. This is the path for an image that does not load

Comment: Are you sure you have necessary permission?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

Comment: `This is the path for an image that does not load`. You should have told us also a path for an image that does load.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20170416-WA0002.jpg. This is the path of the image that loaded in the Imageview

Comment: Check the resolution in pixels of the images. Is it that big images dont load?

Comment: For the image that loaded the resolution is 449x799.For the one that did not load the resolution is 1500x2657

Comment: Couldnt you test with more images? With only one you cannot yet conclude that size matters. Although im pretty sure it does.

Comment: I replaced Glide with Universal ImageLoader.It works perfect!!!